# show that $\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}$ diverges

Tags: integration, analysis

I want to show that this integral diverges
$$\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}$$
i tried to do
$$\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}=\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}=\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{1-\cos^{2}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}=\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos^{2}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}$$

and thus
$$\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}}=\lim_{a\rightarrow0^{+}}\intop_{a}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}}=\lim_{a\rightarrow0^{+}}-\frac{1}{x}=\infty$$

but i don't sure that if $$\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}}$$
diverges so the whole expression diverges, and if it does then why?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote down the integrand correctly? I don't think that diverges. Is it possible you meant $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}{x^2}dx$, which does indeed diverge?

Comment: that certainly does not diverge.

Comment: Maybe Im wrong so can you explain why it doesn't?

Comment: It is well known that $\sin x \leq x$ for all $x\geq 0$. Thus $$
\left| {\int_0^1 {\frac{{\sin ^2 x}}{{x^2 }}dx} } \right| = \int_0^1 {\frac{{\sin ^2 x}}{{x^2 }}dx}  = \int_0^1 {\left( {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}} \right)^2 dx}  \le \int_0^1 {1^2 dx}  = 1.
$$

Comment: and why you need to tell that $$\left|\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}\right|=\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should **not** diverge. $\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$ is bounded over $[0,1]$, which means that its integral over the same range is bounded.

When you split the integral into $\int\frac1{x^2}-\int\frac{\cos^2x}{x^2}$, both of those integrals *do* diverge, so you created an $\infty-\infty$ scenario, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't diverge, in fact $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} \approx .89734$

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$ is defined on $\mathbf R^*$, but it a continuation $\tilde f$to $\mathbf R$, setting $\tilde f(0)=1$ which is *continuous*, and the improper integral of $f$ exists if and only if the integral of $\tilde f$ exists.